# Correct syntax of media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

When I write this rule

```
header
{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Everything is fine and good. But if I wrap it in a media query, it stops working.

```
@media all and(max-width: 5000px)
{
    header
    {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
}
```

The problem arises on the following website:[link](http://www.geckod.com)

If you inspect the stylesheet, you will see a bunch of media queries that don't work. It is a big mistery for me, since they used to.

Comment: try replacing `all` by `screen`

Comment: It turned out to be that a space is required between "and" and the bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed media queries in your CSS. It looks like you need a space between the word "and" and the opening parenthesis.

```
@media only screen and () {}
```

See the good and bad media query on this JSBin demo: http://jsbin.com/ALiHAFu/1/edit

Comment: This seems to be the practical solution, and the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) says “Parse Error” when the space is missing. It seems to me that the [syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#syntax) allows the space to be omitted (the syntax has `S*`, which means any number – including zero – of whitespace), but apparently both browsers and the CSS Validator are more restrictive